# How to set dict index key before looping through data to get key,value?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Trying to parse JSON-data but having trouble to set the a `dict[index]` since the index variable is only present once in the JSON while the rest of the key,values requires a loop to get them. What I have tried is a nested loop, but with no success. Getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Any feedback would be highly appreciated, full example below.

Many thanks,

```
class Premier_league:

    def __init__(self, base_url='https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football'):
        self.base_url = base_url

    def get_standings(self, compSeasons):

        url = self.base_url + '/compseasons/{}/standings'.format(compSeasons)
        print(url)
        # url -> https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/compseasons/274/standings

        params = (
            ('pageSize', '100'),
                )
        response = requests.get(url, params = params).json() # request to obtain the team info

        all_standings = response["tables"][0]['entries']
        info_standings = response['compSeason']


        standings = {} #Store all standings


        #loop to get all info for all standings
        for info in info_standings:
            standing_id = info['label']
            index = standing_id
            standings[index] = \
                {'id' : info['id']}
            for standing in all_standings:
                standings[index] = \
                {
                'team' : standing['team']['name'],
                'team_id' : standing['team']['club']['id'],
                'position' : standing['position'],
                'overall' : standing['overall'],
                'home' : standing['home'],
                'away' : standing['away'],
                }

        f = open("standings_" + str(compSeasons) + ".json","w")

        # pretty prints and writes the same to the json file 
        f.write(json.dumps(standings,indent=4, sort_keys=False))
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prem = Premier_league()
    prem.get_standings(274)
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "2019/20": {
                'id' : info['id']
                'team' : standing['team']['name'],
                'team_id' : standing['team']['club']['id'],
                'position' : standing['position'],
                'overall' : standing['overall'],
                'home' : standing['home'],
                'away' : standing['away'],
    },
    "2019/20": {
                'id' : info['id']
                'team' : standing['team']['name'],
                'team_id' : standing['team']['club']['id'],
                'position' : standing['position'],
                'overall' : standing['overall'],
                'home' : standing['home'],
                'away' : standing['away'],
    },
}
```

Comment: Python dictionaries must have unique keys, in your expected output you would have the key "2019/20" twice. You should probably rethink the output format.

Comment: Oh that explains why it doesn't work, thank you for pointing that out! Will have to rethink the data-structure, thank you for the input!

Comment: Try adding `print(info)` right after `for info in info_standings:`, you'll see that `info_standings` is a `dict`, not a `list` and you enumerated its keys, which are strings like "label". not the dicts you expect.

Comment: Class names should generally follow the `CamelCase` style. I'm not convinced that you actually need a class here, though.

Comment: @AMC the class is much bigger, just pasted the important part of it for the question. Thank you for pointing out improvments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanielP helped solve this be informing me that Python dictionaries must have unique keys, in me expected output I would have the key "2019/20" twice.

So by changing the "index variable" in the dictionary it worked smoothly.

```
def get_standings(self, compSeasons):

    url = self.base_url + '/compseasons/{}/standings'.format(compSeasons)
    print(url)

    params = (
        ('pageSize', '100'),
            )
    response = requests.get(url, params = params).json() # request to obtain the team info

    all_standings = response["tables"][0]['entries']
    season_id = response['compSeason']['id']


    standings = {} #Store all standings


    #loop to get all info for all standings
    for standing in all_standings:
        standing_id = standing['team']['name']
        index = standing_id

        standings[index] = \
        {
        'season_id' : season_id,
        'team_id' : standing['team']['club']['id'],
        'position' : standing['position'],
        'overall' : standing['overall'],
        'home' : standing['home'],
        'away' : standing['away'],
        }


    f = open("standings_" + str(compSeasons) + ".json","w")

    # pretty prints and writes the same to the json file 
    f.write(json.dumps(standings,indent=4, sort_keys=False))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for info in info_standings` only goes thru the keys in that dictionary, like in this minimal example:

```
for v in {'a': 1, 'b': 2}:
    print(v)
```

outputs:

```
a
b
```

In your code, `info` in that loop first got the value `"label"` and you then try to `"label"['label']` which gives that `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` .. the list being that string.

To go thru the whole contents, do:

```
for key, value in {'a': 1, 'b': 2}.items():
    print(key, value)
```

which gives what you want:

```
a 1
b 2
```

Also, you seem to be confused about the JSON structure in the code that follows, so I was not able to fix the rest of the code easily.

I put it to repl.it with some print statements to see what is going on. In general, you can print the intermediate data to see what you have, when you get problems with the parsing. You can run my bit improved version of your code there. If you fix it further but get more problems, I can try helping again. https://repl.it/@ToniAlatalo/WingedSubduedDisk

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to wrap your head around the problem, I seem to have explained myself poorly though. I will put in an expected output in the question to clear it up. Thank you!